# grunt Build does not works on minifying javascript files

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have used a decorator to customize a bootstrap directive. When minimizing i get the error show in snapshot below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L2sg.png)

However with mangle set to False in uglify option it works fine.

```
(function(){

/* global _ */

 'use strict';

angular.module('app.core', [
'ui.router',
'restangular',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.validate'
])
.value('lodash', _).config(['$provide', Decorate]);

function Decorate($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('uibTimepickerDirective', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.templateUrl = 'src/common/custom-bootstrap-template/timePicker.html';
        directive.$$isolateBindings.index = {
            attrName: 'hourActive',
            mode: '@',
            optional: true
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
}

}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is short:

```
$provide.decorator('uibTimepickerDirective', function($delegate) {});
```

Should be:

```
$provide.decorator('uibTimepickerDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {}]);
```

During minification `$delegate` is replaced with `a` and you get error, but string literal `'$delegate'` is not replaced.